# Problema no header

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();    
//Incluindo a conexão com banco de dados
include_once("conexao.php");    
//O campo usuário e senha preenchido entra no if para validar
if((isset($_POST['nome'])) && (isset($_POST['senha']))){
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nome']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);
    $senha = md5($senha);

    //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome = '$usuario' && senha = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

    //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    if(isset($resultado)){
        $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $resultado['niveis_acesso_id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioEmail'] = $resultado['nome'];
        if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1"){
            header("Location: administrativo.php");
        }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2"){
            header("Location: professor.php");
        }else{
            header("Location: aluno.php");
        }
    //Não foi encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    //redireciona o usuario para a página de login
    }else{  
        //Váriavel global recebendo a mensagem de erro
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha Inválido";
        header("Location: administrativo.php");
    }
//O campo usuário e senha não preenchido entra no else e redireciona o usuário para a página de login
}else{
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
    header("Location: administrativo.php");
}
?>
```

Quando eu executo no php, ele da esse erro :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp64\www\login1\valida.php on line 37

Eu realmente não entendi o motivo do erro.

Comment: A linha 37 é qual? geralmente isso é falta de alguma `}`

Comment: A linha 37 é a ultima, na qual tem o  " ?> " , e se pode ver ali que tem o }